# Can't enable callback on my app after native twitter app Login

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, twitter

I have a created a App in which we have a sharing functionality on `twitter`.

if user is login in **General Setting->Twitter->** then we take details from that via `ACAccountStore`.
And If not Login then we ask user to Login through Twitter App.

After Login in Twitter App user can not be redirected to the app.

I have used following code to redirect to twitter app from my app.

I have also not used any `consumerkey` and `secret key` for this.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://"]];
```

How i can call back to my app after login from that native twitter app ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Callback URL:` while creating app on Twitter. The callback URL will open your app after the successful login. [Create URL.](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

[image]

Comment: I have not created any app in twitter (dev.twitter.com).can you tell me how can i pass the This App Name with Open url. we are using this when we are using sharekit

Comment: I guess then there is no way to open your app again.